# mySQL JOIN ON WHERE?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, where-clause

is it possible to add a WHERE into a mysql JOIN statement, for example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site_products JOIN site_trans ON site_products.product_count = site_trans.trans_inventory WHERE site_products.product_id = site_trans.trans_product");
```

is this possible?

Comment: WHERE will be executed after JOIN

Comment: what if to change `WHERE` to `AND`?

Comment: @k102 it will work, you have to use ( and ) after ON, so query will look like this: `SELECT * FROM site_products JOIN site_trans ON (site_products.product_count = site_trans.trans_inventory AND site_products.product_id = site_trans.trans_product)`

Comment: You'd just have to execute it to see that it is indeed possible.

Comment: @Wojtek actualy i know that it's correct (meaning syntax) - i don't know if it's correct in terms of what OP wants

Comment: it works thank you! i've never had to use mySQL before but im beging to like it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes this is possible, but your query may not give the desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM site_products 
JOIN site_trans ON site_products.product_count = site_trans.trans_inventory 
WHERE site_products.product_id = site_trans.trans_product
```

instead, you should write that as an additional JOIN condition like so

```
SELECT * FROM site_products 
JOIN site_trans ON site_trans.trans_inventory = site_products.product_count
     AND site_trans.trans_product = site_products.product_id
```

you may additionally also add a WHERE clause

```
SELECT * FROM site_products 
JOIN site_trans ON site_trans.trans_inventory = site_products.product_count
     AND site_trans.trans_product = site_products.product_id
WHERE site_products.product_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM site_products JOIN site_trans ON (site_products.product_count = site_trans.trans_inventory AND site_products.product_id = site_trans.trans_product)
WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible to use where condition in MYSQL join queries.even you can use multiple where conditions using AND operator.